# For Statement using This vs jQuery Each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, each

I am trying to move from `$.each()` to a `for()` statement but experiencing some issues with the usage of `$(this)` in the later ?

i.e. assume I have this function

```
$('.class').each(function() {

var myVar = $(this);
var myVarSrc = myVar.attr('src');
...
```

The problem I experiencing is that when I attempt to move this to a `for` statement

```
var class = $('.class');
for (var i = 0; i < class.length; i++) {

var myClass = $('.class')[i];
var myClassSrc = myClass.attr('src');
...
```

The later doesn't bind to `each` meaning that `myClassSrc` - if it's the same - will overwrite ? How can I use a `for` statement with `this` ?

Comment: tip: class is a reserved keyword in JavaScript and shouldn't be used for naming variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing `[i]` extracts the native DOM element.

If you do that, you should access the `.src` property directly.

```
var cls = $('.class');
for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {

var myClass = cls[i];
var myClassSrc = myClass.src;
```

...or use the [`eq()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get a jQuery object with the element for the given index:

```
var cls = $('.class');
for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {

var myClass = cls.eq(i);
var myClassSrc = myClass.attr('src');
```

Also notice that I removed the `$('.class')` from inside the loop. You should use the cached version you made before the loop.

I also changed the variable name from `class` to `cls` since `class` is a future reserved word in JavaScript.

---

Based on the comments below, you've come a cross a very common issue. Because you're assigning event handlers inside the `for` loop, and because JavaScript does not have `block scope`, this means that every handler you create in the loop is referencing the same `myClassSrc` variable, which will be set at whatever value it was after the loop completed.

In order to scope a variable, you need to create the event handler in a new variable scope that references the value in the *current* iteration. To do this, we simply pass whatever value we want to retain into a function invocation, and create the handler there:

```
function set_up_handler( elem ) {

    var myClassSrc = elem.src; // <-- now this is a local variable referencing
                               //       the "src" of the element passed in.

    elem.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        alert( myClassSrc );  // <-- this will reference the local "myClassSrc"
    }, false );

}

var cls = $('.class');
for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {

    var myClass = cls[ i ];

    set_up_handler( myClass ); // <-- pass the current element into a function

}
```

Comment: oh great thanks :) so using this logic I would also use `myClass.id` ?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, you can do that to get the ID.

Comment: just can't seem to get this working however :( i.e. in my `for` loop it still isn't iterating across `i` when using `cls.eq(i)`. it still seems to overwrite after each loop ? it only seems to work when I use $(this) ?

Comment: @Tom: Where does it seem to overwrite? Are you assigning an event handler in the loop?

Comment: so basically - I am trying to get the `img` and for each img do something different. the problem is that sometimes I have 2 of the same images and then it seems to overwrite the first img with the data for the second ? so I have 2 images, which should have different data, with the same ? when I use `$(this)` it works but performance suffers ?

Comment: @Tom: I'd need to see some actual code to know what's going on. Perhaps add it to the bottom of your question.

Comment: the problem seems to be the same SRC ? i.e. if the `src` is identical - then `for` loop seems to overwrite each src with the new data ? how can I fix this prob i.e. I think this is why `$(this)` works as it binds to each `src` regardless whereas the `for` loop doesn't ? [thanks so much for responding :)]

Comment: @Tom: `$(this)` simply places the DOM element inside an Object that has methods on it that ultimately just does `element.src` to get the value. Again, if you are adding an event handler in the loop, then you need to invoke a function to retain the proper `src` that you want to reference when the event occurs. So are you binding event handlers in the loop?

Comment: yeah I am. so just little confused how to retain the proper SRC for each element relevant to it's `cls[i]`. It seems that at the moment when the same `src` is found - it overwrites it ? i.e. I can't figure out why `$(this)` works properly but the `for` loop does not ? how would I go about finding the `img` of the 'src' ?

Comment: @Tom: This is a very common issue. First, it has nothing to do with `$(this)`. It has to do with the fact that when you use `.each()`, it invokes a function in each iteration of the loop. This is important because JavaScript does not have *block scope*, only *function scope*. That means that every handler you're creating in the `for` loop is referencing the *same* `myClassSrc` variable. In order to associate the proper value of `myClassSrc` with the proper event handler, you need to pass it into a new function invocation. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: @Tom: Just updated. There are several forms this approach can take, but they all do pretty much the same thing. Whatever value in the loop that you need to retain for future references gets passed into a function which also creates the event handler.

Comment: @Tom: Another thing you should know is that when your event handler is invoked, then `this` inside the handler will refer to the element that received the event. So if all you need is the `src` of the element that was clicked, then you can just do `this.src` inside the handler to get it directly.

Comment: you. rock. problem solved! whoo! :) legend! thankyou sooo much!

Answer (score 1):

I assume the reason you don't want to use `$.each` is because it's slow. The reason it's slow is because it's jQuery. so drop jQuery and use the DOM.

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("class");
for (var i = 0, ii = els.length; i < ii; i++) {
  var el = els[i];
  var src = el.src;
}
```

You will need a shim for `getElementsByClassName` if you care about legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This should be equivalent to your jQuery `foreach` loop:

```
var elemList = $('.class');
for (var i = 0; i < elemList.length; i++) {

    var elem = $(elemList[i]);
    var myClassSrc = elem.attr('src');
    ...
}
```

You don't need to worry about `this` if you use the plain `for` loop.  In the jQuery version, jQuery will bind `this` to the current element in the collection being iterated.  In the non-jQuery version, that is equivalent to `elemList[i]`.

Note that "class" is not the best variable name in the world to use, so I changed it to "elemList".  It is, in fact, a [reserved word](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm) in JavaScript.

Comment: thanks :) how would I go about ensuring that the `src` is retained such that the `for` loop knows correctly that it won't override previous ?